# How do I show fields in a table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

In mysql I can write

```
show fields from <table>;
```

What is the closest equivalent in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use DESCRIBE table.

Comment: You can also use DESCRIBE or DESC in mySQL too.

Comment: Beware that this is not SQL but a SQL\*Plus command. It'll only work with clients that implement it, such as SQL Developer or —of course— SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 10):

In Oracle you can query the dictionary views to get info on the schema objects, for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

alternatively in SQL*Plus you could use the `DESCRIBE` command:

```
DESC my_table
```

Comment: That first query lists the tables, not the fields in the table. You'll get a single row back that has table_name of 'My_TABLE'.

Comment: Nice! Your updated query gives much more detailed output than `describe 'MY_TABLE'` (the accepted answer).